# How to tell if request was from browser or browser extension

Tags: node.js

When I run the following code I get two requests from my Chrome browser and have narrowed it down to one extension just by disabling it in chrome, but my question is how do I tell from my server side code which is the browser request and which is the extensions request

```
var http = require('http');


var server = http.createServer((request, response) => {
    if (request.url == '/favicon.ico'){
        console.log('ignore icon request')
    }else{
        console.log(request.url);
        response.write('hi');
        response.end();
    }
});

server.listen(3000);
```

calling http://localhost:3000/, my output ends up being

```
/
/
ignore icon request
```

so similar to what I did with ignoring the favicon, is there a simple way of ignoring that extension request?

Comment: What other header fileds are set in those requests? If everything is identical, then no, you can't ignore one of these. Actually you have to design your web app to allow duplicate `get` requests; `post` requests are different - but I don't think your extension duplicates these. What extension, btw?

Comment: the extension is safe torrent scanner that comes with utorrent(but thinking about general users might have others that do this too)
as for the headers in the request, they are fairly identical

Comment: headers:{
host:'localhost:3000',
connection:'keep-alive',
'cache-control':'max-age=0',
'upgrade-insecure-requests':'1',
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT10.0;...',
'sec-fetch-user':'?1',
accept:'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8,application/signed-exchange;v=b3;q=0.9',
'sec-fetch-site':'none',
'sec-fetch-mode':'navigate',
'accept-encoding':'gzip,deflate,br',
'accept-language':'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
cookie:'_ga=GA1.1.854158869.1578309551;ASP.NET_SessionId=ambqciz4ejuqhoutvx5emv3g'
},

Comment: headers:{
host:'localhost:3000',
connection:'keep-alive',
'user-agent':'Mozilla/5.0(WindowsNT10.0;...',
accept:'*/*',
'sec-fetch-site':'cross-site',
'sec-fetch-mode':'cors',
'accept-encoding':'gzip,deflate,br',
'accept-language':'en-GB,en-US;q=0.9,en;q=0.8',
cookie:'_ga=GA1.1.854158869.1578309551;ASP.NET_SessionId=ambqciz4ejuqhoutvx5emv3g'
},